# Why doesn't deep copy of array work using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to deep copy an array of objects but it doesn't work. I am using React, but here the problem is pure JavaScript.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(value);
```

Value is value from parent component.

```
const onClickFunction = (arr) => {

    const newClonedArray = selected.map((a) => ({
        ...a
    }));
    // try to clone selected array 
    // i am also try with 
    // let clonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selected))
    // also no work

    const result = intersectionBy(arr, newClonedArray, "id");
    // here return only common items from two array using lodash library

    setSelected(result);

    console.log('selected  item right now should be changed', selected)
    // NO RESULT IS NOT CHANGED

    result.forEach((i) => {
        handleItemClick(i); // no important for now
    });
}
```

Inside the function I explained in detail what the problem was.

Why doesn't the array deep copy?

Selected state is array like ->

```
[
 { id : 1 , name: 'test' },
 { id : 2 , name: 'test 2' }
]
```

after deep copy i need to change selected array to be like ->

```
[
 { id : 1 , name: 'test' , title : 'title 1 ' },
 { id : 2 , name: 'test 2' , title : 'title 2 '  }
]
```

i just want to copy some values from some string.

Comment: To clone array use `const clonedArray = Array.from(yourArray)`, or `const clonedArray = [...yourArray]`

Comment: State is updated asynchronously and state is also constant within a particular render of a component; as a result, component can't see the updated state until it re-renders. Use the `useEffect` hook to see the updated state: `useEffect(() => console.log(selected), [selected])`

Comment: Idruskis i am try but again no work. 

@Yousaf can you help me with code ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `Object.assign` or `JSON.stringify` with `JSON.parse`

```js
var selected = [
 { id : 1 , name: 'test' },
 { id : 2 , name: 'test 2' }
]

var newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selected));

//do whatever you want to on newArray
newArray.map(a => a.title = a.name);

console.log("selected",selected)
console.log("newArray", newArray)
```

Comment: No work. Problem is in state. State is not updated